RocketReach Lookup webhook to Google Sheets via Apps Script
Trying to make a Google Apps script so that everytime I press "Get Contact" on RocketReach (a Lead Generation app) and it displays the profile of the contact including email, it goes to the webhook I deployed via Google Apps Script and pastes the completed lookup into my Google Sheets.
Here is the code I used:
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Company Leads'); // Change 'Sheet1' to your sheet name
    
    // Log the entire event object
    Logger.log("Received event: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    
    // Check if postData is defined
    if (!e || !e.postData) {
      throw new Error("No postData available in the event object");
    }
    
    // Log the postData contents
    Logger.log("postData contents: " + e.postData.contents);
    
    var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

    // Log the parsed data
    Logger.log("Parsed data: " + JSON.stringify(data));

    // Check if all required fields are present
    if (!data.full_name || !data.current_employer || !data.occupation || !data.email) {
      throw new Error("Incomplete data received. Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    
    var fullName = data.full_name;
    var nameParts = fullName.split(' ');
    var firstName = nameParts[0];
    var lastName = nameParts.slice(1).join(' '); // Join the rest of the parts as last name
    
    var currentEmployer = data.current_employer;
    var occupation = data.occupation;
    var email = data.email;

    sheet.appendRow([new Date(), currentEmployer, firstName, lastName, occupation, email]);
    
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({result: 'success'})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.message);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({result: 'error', message: error.message})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

However it's not displaying any contacts to my sheet. It keeps giving me the log "Received event: undefined" and "Error: No postData available in the event object".
What am I missing?

error you are encountering indicates that the doPost function is not receiving the expected payload, which suggests that the webhook might not be configured correctly, or the test method you are using might not be sending the payload in the correct format

doublecheck your configuration setup. you can perform manual test like:
function testDoPost() {
  var testData = {
    postData: {
      contents: JSON.stringify({
        full_name: "John Doe",
        current_employer: "Example Corp",
        occupation: "Software Engineer",
        email: "john.doe@example.com"
      })
    }
  };
  
  var result = doPost(testData);
  Logger.log("Test result: " + result.getContent());
}


Thank you. Upon manual testing, it worked fine. After an actual run (looking up a contact on RocketReach and then running the code), it's displaying the same error.
